# Why doesn't sleep work?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ffi

Why does `c_sleep` return immediately in the following code?

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
import Foreign.C.Types
import Data.Time.Clock
import Control.Concurrent

foreign import ccall unsafe "unistd.h sleep" 
    c_sleep :: CUInt -> IO CUInt

main :: IO ()
main = do
    getCurrentTime >>= print . utctDayTime
    c_sleep 10     >>= print                -- this doesn't sleep
    getCurrentTime >>= print . utctDayTime
    threadDelay $ 10 * 1000 * 1000          -- this does sleep
    getCurrentTime >>= print . utctDayTime
```

```
$ ghc --make Sleep.hs && ./Sleep
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Sleep.hs, Sleep.o )
Linking Sleep ...
29448.191603s
10
29448.20158s
29458.211402s

$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.3

$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.20.0.3
using version 1.20.0.0 of the Cabal library
```

**Note:** Actually, I would like to use [`sleep`](http://man.cx/sleep%283%29) in C code to simulate some heavy computation in a function `func` and call *that* function in Haskell, but that doesn't work either, probably for the same reasons.

Comment: It's possible that the GHC runtime is using signals that disrupt the `sleep`.     Have you checked the error code? Perhaps you should wrap it in a loop to restart it if it gets interrupted (in which case it's best to use `nanosleep` for higher precision).

Comment: @Rufflewind: `sleep` doesn't return an error code, but the unslept amount in seconds :/. Haven't tried `nanosleep` yet, but `usleep` doesn't work either.

Comment: The error code is "returned" via the `errno` variable. Wrap `(c_sleep 10)` inside `throwErrnoIf (/= 0) "sleep"` and you'll see that it's being interrupted.

Comment: See also [this bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/850). Not exactly related to this issue but it does say the RTS, even the single-threaded one, sends signals periodically, which will interrupt any `sleep` call.

Comment: @Rufflewind: Thanks. Jeez, why doesn't `man 3 sleep` mention the `errno` update? I guess I'll have too write a `void nanosleep_loop(uint32_t)`, since `nanosleep` gets affected too. The ticket probably answers this question, so feel free to add one.

Comment: Actually, you're right, the docs for `sleep` don't mention anything about `errno` at all (I was reading `nanosleep` instead).  However, it does say if the return value is nonzero, then it was due to interruption by a signal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GHC's [RTS appears to use signals](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Signals) for its [own](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Profiling) [purposes](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Scheduler), which means it won't be long before a sleep gets interrupted by one of these signals.  I don't think it's a bug either, the runtime does [come with its own territory](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/850), so to speak.  The Haskellian approach would be to use `threadDelay` but it's not easy for a C program to access that without some trickery.

The [proper way](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Signals#RTSAlarmSignalsandForeignLibraries) is to repeatedly resume the sleep despite interruptions from other signals.  I recommend using `nanosleep` since `sleep` only has a precision of seconds and the signals appear to occur much more frequently than that.

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

/* same as 'sleep' except it doesn't get interrupted by signals */
int keep_sleeping(unsigned long sec) {
    struct timespec rem, req = { (time_t) sec, 0 }; /* warning: may overflow */
    while ((rem.tv_sec || rem.tv_nsec) && nanosleep(&req, &rem)) {
        if (errno != EINTR) /* this check is probably unnecessary */
            return -1;
        req = rem;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All concurrency primitives always have a clawback statement that they may block for less time than specified - they may return spuriously. This is nothing to do with the language, it is the nature of concurrency, so if you want to wait for exactly the specified amount of time, in any language you need to construct a loop checking the clock after the sleep.

Comment: While this is true, one wouldn't expect a valid `(u)sleep()` call that usually works well in its single thread C domain to get interrupted _immediately after the call_. Even more so if one didn't use `-threaded` and/or concurrency.

Comment: @Zeta The expectation is wrong then. No one ever specifies the reason for spurious wakeup - it is _spurious_; it doesn't say `"may wake up *only* because the application interrupted itself"`. I don't think it makes sense to code intuitively against unspecified behaviour - like we don't assume an uninitialized `int` is zero in C.